# How to move the search bar to the center of the screen?

Tags: html, css

This might be a stupid question, but I'm new. I think the problem is in the 'position' property. Already tried everything, the search box jumps from side to side. Maybe a bug in html

```css
.header{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}

.header::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 1.38%, rgba(105, 0, 70, 0.38) 20.04%, #000000 100.0%);
}

/* .header_content{
    position: relative;
} */

.search{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.search_bar{
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color:rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.38);
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tall Lorenc</title>
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/3/3.0.1/iconify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="welcome" class="header" style="background-image: url('/img/header1.jpg');">
        <div class="container">
            
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div class="header_content">
                        <div style="width: 700px;">
                            <div class="search">
                                <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Which type of track are you looking for?">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure your HTML is valid. Any highlighted red closing tags mean the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Please strip down your code example to only include the most relevant parts. For example, the `container` class is not used, and I do not think you will need the `header` element for your question as well. This will make it easier of others to read and answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tall Lorenc</title>
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/3/3.0.1/iconify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="welcome" class="header" style="background-image: url('/img/header1.jpg');">
        <div class="container">
            
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div class="header_content">
                        <div class="search-wrapper">
                            <div class="search">
                                <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Which type of track are you looking for?">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 1.38%, rgba(105, 0, 70, 0.38) 20.04%, #000000 100.0%);
}

/* .header_content{
    position: relative;
} */

.search{
    position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width:700px;
}

.search-wrapper{
  width:100%
}

.search_bar{
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color:rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.38);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, but what if we create a div not in the container, but outside it?

Comment: Which div do you mean to create outside of it?

Comment: div with search bar

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer, this should work!

I just commented out the div style="width: 700px;" lines
Having div within div can get very complex as the child div will always inherit the styling of the parent div. Check your divs and see if you truly need all of those nested into one another.

I also changed the width of the search bar to 90% instead of 100% so you can see it actually centered.

```css
.header{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}

.header::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 1.38%, rgba(105, 0, 70, 0.38) 20.04%, #000000 100.0%);
}

/* .header_content{
    position: relative;
} */

.search{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.search_bar{
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color:rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.38);
    width: 90%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tall Lorenc</title>
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/3/3.0.1/iconify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="welcome" class="header" style="background-image: url('/img/header1.jpg');">
        <div class="container">
            
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div class="header_content">
                        <!-- <div style="width: 700px;"> -->
                            <div class="search" >
                                <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Which type of track are you looking for?">
                            </div>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey J-D, as it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details on what you have actually changed and how that should fix the problem asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn more `HTML` and `CSS`, so that *you* can understand what's really going on.

Now, with your current set up, the simplest thing you can do is this:

```css
.header_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I tried this out, and maybe I don't have all of your `CSS`, but I couldn't figure out why it was pushed slightly to the right. Either way, if this `.header_content` container correctly fits its parent, then you should be good to go, because the children of `.header_content` centered correctly.

Since I don't understand your full setup, this may not be helpful to you, but I think you've overcomplicated your HTML. This is all you should need, from my understanding:

```css
/* styles.css */

/* You may consider switching your rgba()'s to the modern syntax. No "a" in rgb, and no commas. Just a "/" to seperate the alpha value. I changed them in my example, as you can see. */

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 1.38%, rgb(105 0 70 / 0.38) 20.04%, #000000 100.0%); /* I'm not sure if this was it's intended use, since you had it in a ::before element, but this looked more correct in my testing. */
  display: grid; /* You could also do display: flex, but I think this may be more accurate to your needs. */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr; /* This will make sure your search bar (the second element in the grid), will always take up the majority of the space, while the sides remain even. */
  place-items: center; /* This ensures each grid item is placed in the center of it's section. */
}

/* This styling isn't necessary to complete your task */
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* This ensures our search container sizes properly. You may also consider the commented out width value instead. */
.search {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 325px; /* This ensures the search bar never cuts out the placeholder text. */
  /* width: 325px; */
}

.search_bar {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  /* line-height: 120%; I don't think this is necessary. */
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(58 58 58 / 0.38);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<header>

  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Which type of track are you looking for?">
  </div>

</header>
```

You'll notice in this example, that the search bar is technically a few pixels to the right, since we don't have any content on the right of it. If we were to remove the `.container` div with the `Content` text, it would work best with a `display: flex; justify-content: center;` instead of `display: grid;`. I'm just not sure what you full use case is.

Now let's say you want to guarantee it's always 100% center, no matter what kind of content you have around it... (I wouldn't recommend this in most cases, but perhaps it will help in your use case) With my `HTML`, just change the `CSS` to this:

```css
/* styles.css */

/* This line below I do in every project, because it makes the sizing and positioning as I expect it to be, rather than chosen by the browser which is different depending on the element. */

*,
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 1.38%, rgb(105 0 70 / 0.38) 20.04%, #000000 100.0%);
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}


/* This styling isn't necessary to complete your task */

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.search {
  width: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* If you also want it vertically aligned to the center, uncomment the below lines and remove the above transform */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.search_bar {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: rgb(58 58 58 / 0.38);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<header>

  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Which type of track are you looking for?">
  </div>

</header>
```

Once again, I think that these kinds of things just require more `HTML` and `CSS` knowledge. I'm sure you'll grow to understand this stuff in time. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

a better way of doing this is using flex

```css
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.container{
display:flex;
height:100vh;
background-color:lightgreen;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```